# Normalization - removing transitive dependency

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a rules engine which will be executed in code, but I have a problem defining a properly normalized database structure for it:

- There are templates from which rules can be derived
- Each template will define a set of fields that can be used by a rule
- Each rule will define a set of conditions that can be tested against the fields

So for example I may have a template 'Bicycle' that would have fields 'Wheel Size' and 'Number of gears'.

I could then create a number of rules against that template such as:

- 'Childrens bike': Wheel Size = 14"
- 'Mountain bike': Wheel Size = 26" and Number of Gears = 27
- 'City bike': Wheel Size = 26" and Number of Gears = 3

This is a simplified version of the database design I have so far:

[image: Database diagram]

And the associated SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE RuleTemplate(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Field(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    RuleTemplateId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES RuleTemplate(Id),
    Name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [Rule](
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    RuleTemplateId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES RuleTemplate(Id),
    Name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Condition(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    RuleId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Rule](Id),
    FieldId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Field(Id),
    ComparisonValue NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL
)
```

This design is vulnerable to anomalies as a rule can contain conditions which refer to fields from a different template than the rule.

Can anyone suggest a table design which will overcome this weakness?

Answer (score 1):

I think that same Field can participate in several templates so Field and RuleTemplate is actually M:M.

Next, you can't enforce rules like 'Condition should refer only to Fields that belong to Rule's template' in a declarative way, and keep this schema normalized. But you can control rules like this using triggers. If you see a lot of weird questions like this, usually it means that probably we can choose better base entities for a subject area.

It doesn't mean that this schema can't be used. No, it is normalized and good enough to be used in application. But data integrity should be checked on application side. It is natural way to deal with scheme like this. GUI should never show wrong columns in rule designer.

[image: new schema]

Concerning another set of entities. Logically every rule is an expression. Expression is a tree-like structure. Unfortunately relational schema is not a good fit for information like this. You'll meet a lot of difficulties further on the way, for example, type of ComparisionValue column should be different for different fields. Solution can be XML which store expression. It is better option for expressions, type-safe and way more flexible.

Answer (score -1):

Don't you simply want to have the structure

Templates -> Fields -> Rules -> conditions

This will ensure that rules are associated with the correct fields and the correct fields are associated with the template

Comment: OK, but in that case a Rule could be associated with more than one template, so I don't think that is the solution.

Comment: You could overcome this by adding a second key so that the rule table was keyed both on template ID and Field ID etc